# Using GpuMat with Caffe

Tags: c++, gpu, caffe, opencv3.0

In the standard caffe [example code here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp#L176) we have:

```
void Classifier::WrapInputLayer(std::vector<cv::Mat>* input_channels) {
  Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];

  int width = input_layer->width();
  int height = input_layer->height();
  float* input_data = input_layer->mutable_cpu_data();
  for (int i = 0; i < input_layer->channels(); ++i) {
    cv::Mat channel(height, width, CV_32FC1, input_data);
    input_channels->push_back(channel);
    input_data += width * height;
  }
}
```

If I am using `cv::cuda::GpuMat` can I rewrite the code to this?

```
void Classifier::WrapInputLayer(std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat>* input_channels) {
  Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];

  int width = input_layer->width();
  int height = input_layer->height();
  float* input_data = input_layer->mutable_gpu_data();
  for (int i = 0; i < input_layer->channels(); ++i) {
    cv::cuda::GpuMat channel(height, width, CV_32FC1, input_data); // OK I hope?
    input_channels->push_back(channel);
    input_data += width * height;
  }
}
```

Here we use [this `GpuMat` constructor for initialising to a GPU memory pointer](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1). Then [`Preprocess()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp#L189) can be updated to use the relevant GPU versions of the OpenCV interface.

Are there any pitfalls that await me?

**NOTE**: I have just made the change and it appears to work as expected, but there is a dearth of information on this topic when I check via Google, so perhaps this can serve as a canonical example?